# Can't install composer in aApanel for laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, centos, composer-php

I am trying to deploy a laravel project to linux vps. the command "composer install" returns me this error

```
'Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev) Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform. Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run composer update or composer update <package name>. Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

Problem 1 - league/flysystem is locked to version 1.0.70 and an update of this package was not requested. - league/flysystem 1.0.70 requires ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension. Problem 2 - minishlink/web-push is locked to version v5.2.5 and an update of this package was not requested. - minishlink/web-push v5.2.5 requires ext-gmp * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gmp extension. Problem 3 - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet is locked to version 1.12.0 and an update of this package was not requested. - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.12.0 requires ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension. Problem 4 - web-token/jwt-core is locked to version v1.3.10 and an update of this package was not requested. - web-token/jwt-core v1.3.10 requires ext-gmp * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gmp extension. Problem 5 - web-token/jwt-util-ecc is locked to version v1.3.10 and an update of this package was not requested. - web-token/jwt-util-ecc v1.3.10 requires ext-gmp * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gmp extension. Problem 6 - minishlink/web-push v5.2.5 requires ext-gmp * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gmp extension. - laravel-notification-channels/webpush 5.0.1 requires minishlink/web-push ^5.0 -> satisfiable by minishlink/web-push[v5.2.5]. - laravel-notification-channels/webpush is locked to version 5.0.1 and an update of this package was not requested.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files: - /www/server/php/71/etc/php.ini You can also run php --ini in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode. Alternatively, you can run Composer with --ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo --ignore-platform-req=ext-gmp --ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo --ignore-platform-req=ext-gmp --ignore-platform-req=ext-gmp --ignore-platform-req=ext-gmp to temporarily ignore these required extensions.'
```

can't generate a key also. 'php artisan key:generate' returns me this error.

```
'PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Dotenv\Dotenv' not found in /www/wwwroot/.../.../bootstrap/app.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /www/wwwroot/../../artisan(18): require() #1 {main} thrown in /www/wwwroot/..../.../bootstrap/app.php on line 6

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Dotenv\Dotenv' not found in /www/wwwroot/.../.../bootstrap/app.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /www/wwwroot/.../.../artisan(18): require() #1 {main} thrown in /www/wwwroot/..../../bootstrap/app.php on line 6'
```

Please help. I am using composer version 2.2.11.

I tried by change php versions of my project, but it wont help.

Comment: seems some of the extensions are missing in php configuration. fileinfo, ext-gmp are the example from the first error. Fix these errors before proceeding next.

Comment: Thanks, thats works, I installed fileinfo(), and gmp package, solve my problem.